# How can I use the bootstrap utility functions in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

In my javascript console it works when I do this`$('.collapse').collapse();`,
but it does not work when I append it to the bottom of my application.js file.
My application.js file looks like this

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Why doesn't it work when I add it to my application.js???

Thank you

Comment: adding `//= require_self` helps?, also write code in `$(document).ready(){}` function

Comment: @RaviMariya Yes! //= require_self was done by default by rails I believe but the missing piece was really to put my code within $(document).ready(){}. My understanding is that I was trying to execute some javascript on the DOM without it being fully loaded first. Thank you !!